# Trim Newline `\n` from Process Return in Julia

Tags: julia

How to trim newlines in Julia when returning a process.

```
julia> read(`echo hi`,String)
"hi\n"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `readchomp`:

```
julia> readchomp(`echo hi`)
"hi"
```